# ¿Cómo recibir cadenas en un ciclo for?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando recibir cadenas y almacenarlas con un ciclo **for**, sin embargo, omite el ingreso del primer elemento. Ya intenté poniendo un `nextLine()` por debajo y omite más líneas:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println("Ingresa la asignatura ["+(i+1)+"]");
    asignaturas[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```

Muchísimas gracias por su ayuda!

Comment: [El código que has puesto funciona](https://onlinegdb.com/rkGIZnvgu)

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras funciona correctamente, por lo que asumo que no esta completo. Ese error ocurre cuando queremos leer un tipo de dato `numérico`, sea del tipo que sea y seguidamente queremos leer un `String`. El siguiente articulo explica el porque, y algunas maneras de solucionarlo [Problema con nextLine()](https://tazasdejava.blogspot.com/2017/02/problema-con-nextline-se-salta-una-linea.html).

Otra forma de evitar tener ese problema, es utilizar la clase `BufferedReader` para leer datos. Te dejo dos métodos para leer datos String y Int como ejemplo.

```
   public String readLine(){
        String str = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            str = br.readLine();
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Wrong Input.");
        }
        return str;
    }
   
  public int readInt(){
    boolean b;
    int num = 0;
    do{
        try{
            num = Integer.parseInt(readLine());
            b = true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Wrong Input, put in a valid input.");
            b = false;
        }
    }while(!b);
    
    return num;
}
```

Para poder utilizar estos métodos necesitas hacer los siguientes import:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

yo tengo este código, solo mira bien la definición del arreglo, puede que sea eso.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Po {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // inicializa variables
    String[] palabras = new String[10];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
       
        palabras[x] = sc.nextLine();

    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        System.out.println(palabras[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Si no estás seguro, mejor pide/espera aclaraciones del OP para dar una respuesta certera.